# Wordpress Search breaking after apostrophe

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to debug some behavior on my site in regards to search. What's happening is I will want to find something like: `What's your Customers' Love Language?`, and it will display it if I type `What'`. The problem is as soon as I type anything after the apostrophe, it suddenly can't find my post.

This is happening for all posts with this kind of title.

Here's the code for my search form(using [this](https://themeforest.net/item/smartmag-responsive-retina-wordpress-magazine/6652608) theme):

```
    <div class="search">
                <form role="search" action="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>" method="get">
                    <input type="text" name="s" class="<?php echo implode(' ', $classes); ?>" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>" placeholder="<?php _e('Search...', 'bunyad'); ?>"/>
                    <button class="search-button" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                </form>
            </div> <!-- .search -->
```

The weird thing is it's recognizing the apostrophes, so I don't think I need to do special characters sanitization. It's using default WP search with no extra stuff added on, so I'm really stumped.

Any help that could be offered would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Wordpress runs `wptexturize()` function which transformations quotes into smart quotes so instead of `'` you see `’` therefore when you search for `what’s` nothing will be returned because although the post has it spelled like that in actuality it's spelled `what's`.

The way to fix this is to prevent this function from running by putting 
  `add_filter('run_wptexturize', '__return_false');` in your `function.php` file.

Look here for more info:

[Wordpress replacing single quotes with search-unfriendly ones](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/17926)

[Code Reference - wptexturize()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wptexturize/)

[Disable wptexturize()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/run_wptexturize/)